# Sonar / findbugs fails when root project doesn't contains any classes

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, findbugs

In a Java project, I'm using Sonar with Maven and it's work fine with "sonar way" profile. But when switching to the "Sonar way with Findbugs" profile, it fails :

*"Can not execute Sonar: Can not execute Findbugs: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled classes."*

The project is correctly build before the execution of Sonar. But the root module / project doesn't contains any classes. So target/classes is empty

My project is composed of several modules and a root pom.xml

Project

|*_* Module 1

|*_* Module 2

|*_* Module 3

pom.xml

Sonar is running fine for every modules and try to analyze the root project but this one doesn't contains any classes so it fails.

Is there a way to exclude the root project / module (exclude root module is not possible) or tell sonar to only generate a warning in this case or another solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command do you run? "mvn clean install sonar:sonar" or "mvn clean install" and then "mvn sonar:sonar"?

Comment: David, I'm using Jenkins. I do a clean install followed by a sonar analysys after the build keeping the default options.

Comment: I tried a simple "mvn clean install" followed by "mvn sonar:sonar" : same problem...

Comment: Is it specific to this project? Could you run the analysis of the following project sample by following the README file: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco ?

Comment: David, no problem running this one...

Comment: Can you confirm your root module is really an aggregator pom, ie with `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and no source folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not facing a sonar or findbugs problem, but you probably 
have a maven specific problem, e.g. a problem with your multi module pom - you actually even stated it "target/classes is empty". Focus on that before focusing on sonar or findbugs.
As a workaround, try setting up a jenkins build for a specific module first. When this is properly built with class files in your target folder, add a sonar goal to your jenkins project and I'd expect it to work.

p.s.: Compare:
[Maven sonar findbugs fails with no source to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228803/maven-sonar-findbugs-fails-with-no-source-to-compile/17230908#17230908)