# Maven sonar findbugs fails with no source to compile

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a multiple module project and i'm trying to configure it with sonar. But sonar Findbugs quality profile fails when i execute

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

(after building the project ) from root. I got following exception.

```
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project catalog-management-system: Can not execute Sonar
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:149)
at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:62)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:101)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanContainer.doStart(ScanContainer.java:147)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scanRecursively(ScanTask.java:56)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scanRecursively(ScanTask.java:54)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:49)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doStart(TaskContainer.java:188)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.executeTask(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:73)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.doStart(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:62)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doStart(BootstrapContainer.java:104)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:88)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:72)
at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
... 23 more
   Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled.    Please build project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled classes.
at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsConfiguration.getFindbugsProject(FindbugsConfiguration.java:84)
at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:107)
... 43 more
```

But when i execute sonar:sonar for certain module which has packaging type jar or war it succeed. I think it fails because it trying to find compiled source for parent project. Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Findbugs requires that your source code has been compiled. If you follow [Sonar documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven), here's what you should do:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Then everything should work.

Comment: actually this didn't seem to work with the current version of Sonar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today.  This is a really old question but I thought I would add my analysis / workaround.

We have a practically empty WAR project with just some landing page functionality (images, index.jsp, ...).  There is no source in this project (no src/main/java).

This error started coming up in our pipeline while I was on vacation last month but no changes had been made to this sub-module.  So I am assuming a new plugin version was added to our managed pipeline.

So it seems if Sonar/Findbugs can't find a 'target/classes' directory it defaults over to 'WEB-INF' and trips over the 'index.jsp'.

To *fix* (workaround) the problem, I added a 'src/main/java/.../Dummy.java' class and now during compile the 'target/classes' directory is created and SonarQube/Findbugs is happy.

Feels like a bug... but I wouldn't know where to raise the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

If you run the above instead of `mvn sonar:sonar`, Maven skips the tests and generates the reports without any error.

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of [Fabrice's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17230908/1005481) that he gave last year.